# DELETE FROM table WHERE var = value does not remove entries

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I fetched some data from a mdb file in c# via

```
"SELECT * FROM " + listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem) + " WHERE Note = '" + listBox2.GetItemText(listBox2.SelectedItem).Replace("'","\'") + "'";
```

which selects the right data, here it is

```
SELECT * FROM Main WHERE Note ='Hello'
```

The mdb data structure looks like this being plotted as a CSV-file:

```
"Record ID";Status;Placement;Private;Category;Note;Blob
14341665;4;2147483647;True;3;"""Hello"" - Neues
```

But when I try to remove entries with

```
"DELETE FROM " + listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem) + " WHERE \"Record ID\" LIKE '" + dr[0] + "';";
```

or

```
"DELETE FROM " + listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem) + " WHERE \"Record ID\" = '" + dr[0] + "';";
```

which looks like for instance

```
DELETE FROM Main WHERE "Record ID" LIKE '14341665';
```

The entries just stay there. I can rerun the select command even restart my application, the mdb is not changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is record ID a numeric field? If so, lose the quotes.

```
DELETE FROM Main WHERE [Record ID] = 14341665;
```

Note that spaces in field (column) names will always be a problem. Such columns names have to be enclosed in square brackets, as do columns named with reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

The record id is numeric, so don't put apostrophes around it:

```
"DELETE FROM " + listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem) + " WHERE \"Record ID\" = " + dr[0]
```

Note: You should avoid using `select *` in production code, you should specify the data that you want returned. Also, you should use parameterised queries instead of concatenating values into the query.

Answer (score 0):

if i remember correctly, "like" only works on string data, please check the data type of Record ID.

If Record ID is numeric, you may want to use database's conversion function to convert it into string before filtering using "like".

btw, remember to make sure that dr[0] is properly escaped.